# rm not freeing diskspace

Tags: linux, tomcat, logging

I've `rm`'ed a 2.5gb log file - but it doesn't seemed to have freed any space.

I did:

```
rm /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
```

then this:

```
df -hT
```

and `df` reported my `/opt` mount still at 100% used.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Depending on the total size of your partition using -h may not show much change. But as others pointed out tomcat probably still has the file open.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321618/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Restart tomcat, if the file is in use and you remove it, the space becomes available when that process finishes.

Comment: Yep, you're right - files are reference-counted in *nix, and as long as there's an reference (i.e. an open fd), it'll still be there even though there are no links left to the inode.

Comment: The best to do in this cases is to echo "" > application.log. This will free your disk instantly without having to restart your tomcat.

Comment: with `lsof +L1` you can find which process is being used and prevent to free the space.

Answer (score 23):

As others suggested, the file probably is still opened by other processes. To find out by which ones, you can do

```
lsof /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
```

which lists you the processes. Probably you will find tomcat in that list.

Answer (score 10):

#### Your Problem:

Its possible that a running program is still holding on to the file.

#### Your Solution:

Per the other answers here, you can simply shutdown tomcat to stop it from holding on to the file.

If that is not an option, or if you simply want more details, check out this question: [Find and remove large files that are open but have been deleted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68523/find-and-remove-large-files-that-are-open-but-have-been-deleted) - it suggests some harsher ways to deal with it that may be more useful to your situation.

---

#### More Details:

The linux/unix filesystem considers "opened" files to be another name for them. rm removes the "name" from the file as seen in the directory tree. Until the handles are closed, the files still has more "names" and so the file still exists.  The file system doesn't reap files until they are completely unnamed.

It might seem a little odd, but doing it this way allows for useful things like enabling symlinks. Symlinks can essentially be treated as an alternate name for the same file.

**This is why it is important to always call your languages equivalent to close()** on a file handle if you are done with it. This notifies the OS that the file is no longer being used. *Although sometimes this cant be helped* - which is likely the case with Tomcat. Refer to [Bill Karwin's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/332657/42082) to read why.

Depending on the file-system, this is usually implemented as a sort of reference count, so there may not be any real names involved. It can also get weird if things like stdin and stderr are redirected to a file or another bytestream (most commonly done with services).

This whole idea is closely related to the concept of '[inodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode)', so if you are the curious type, i'd recommend checking that out first.

#### Discussion

It doesn't work so well anymore, but you used to be able to update the entire OS, start up a new http-daemon using the new libraries, and finally close the old one when no more clients are being serviced with it (releasing the old handles) . http clients wouldn't even miss a beat.

Basicly, you can completely wipe out the kernel and all the libraries "from underneath" running programs.  But since the "name" still exists for the older copies, the file still exists in memory/disk for that particular program. Then it would be a matter of restarting all the services etc. While this is an advanced usage scenario, it is a reason why some unix system have years of up-time on record.

Answer (score 9):

Restarting Tomcat will release any hold Tomcat has on the file. However, to avoid restarting Tomcat (e.g. if this is a production environment and you don't want to bring the services down unncessarily), you can usually just overwrite the file:

```
cp /dev/null /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
```

Or even shorter and more direct:

```
> /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
```

I use these methods all the time to clear log files for currently running server processes in the course of troubleshooting or disk clearing. This leaves the inode alone but clears the actual file data, whereas trying to delete the file often either doesn't work or at the very least confuses the running process' log writer.

Answer (score 6):

As FerranB and Paul Tomblin have noted on this thread, the file is in use and the disk space won't be freed until the file is closed.

The problem is that you can't signal the Catalina process to close `catalina.out`, because the file handle isn't under control of the java process.  It was opened by shell I/O redirection in `catalina.sh` when you started up Tomcat.  Only by terminating the Catalina process can that file handle be closed.

There are two solutions to prevent this in the future:

- Don't allow output from Tomcat apps to go into `catalina.out`.  Instead use the `swallowOutput` property, and configure log channels for output.  Logs managed by log4j can be rotated without restarting the Catalina process.
- Modify catalina.sh to pipe output to [cronolog](http://www.cronolog.org) instead of simply redirecting to `catalina.out`.  That way cronolog will rotate logs for you.

Comment: It bothers me a lot when I see the .sh scripts used to log output. Thanks for giving a solution for tomcat! Proper redirection is the best bet, but incidentally, you may be able to truncate the file if you are in a pinch: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68532

Comment: @Ape-inago, yes thanks for that tip. That's good in a pinch, as you say. But setting up proper log rotation is a more long-term solution.

Answer (score 6):

the best solution is using 'echo' ( as @ejoncas' suggestion ):

```
$ echo '' > huge_file.log
```

This operation is quite safe and fast(remove about 1G data per second), especially when you are operating on your production server.

Don't simply remove this file using 'rm' because firstly you have to stop the process writing it, otherwise the disk won't be freed.

refer to: http://siwei.me/blog/posts/how-to-deal-with-huge-log-file-in-production

## UPDATED： the origin of my story

in 2013, when I was working for youku.com, on the Saturday, I found one core server was down, the reason is : disk is full ( with log files)

so I simplely `rm log_file.log` ( without stopping the web app proccess) but found: 1. no disk space was freed  and: 2. the log file was actually not seen to me.

so I have to restart my web-server( an Rails app ) and the disk space was finally freed.

This is a quite important lesson to me. It told me that `echo '' > log_file.log` is the correct way to free disk space if you don't want to stop the running process which is writing log to this file.

Comment: Per http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68523/find-and-remove-large-files-that-are-open-but-have-been-deleted it maybe faster to simply tell the file-system that the rest of the bytes are not needed via truncation.

Answer (score 3):

If something still has it open, the file won't actually go away.  You probably need to signal catalina somehow to close and re-open its log files.

Answer (score 3):

If there is a second hard link to the file then it won't be deleted until that is removed as well.

Comment: That's a good point, it's worth a search for another 2.5GB file on the same filesystem (hard links cannot span across filesystems).

Answer (score 2):

Enter the command to check which deleted files has occupied memory

```
 $ sudo lsof | grep deleted
```

It will show the deleted file that still holds memory.

Then kill the process with pid or name

```
$ sudo kill <pid>
$ df -h
```

check now you will have the same memory

**If not type the command  below to see which file is occupying memory**

```
# cd /
# du --threshold=(SIZE)
```

mention any size it will show which files are occupying above the threshold size and delete the file

Comment: In my case lsof | grep deleted is not showing anything

Answer (score -2):

Is the rm journaled/scheduled?  Try a 'sync' command for force the write.